# Example for a functor $F:Mod(A)\rightarrow Mod(B)$

Tags: category-theory, functors

I'm trying to find a *simple* example for a functor $F$ between modules, which is **non linear** and I don't really know how to approach this. Intuitively, I'm thinking matrix modules. A hint would be appreciated.

Comment: What about a constant functor with nonzero value ?

Comment: What do you mean with nonzero value? Do you mean the constant nonzero functor? Such that $F(M)=M_0, \forall M\in Mod(A)$?

Comment: I mean *a* constant nonzero functor, so yes, $F(M) = M_0$ for some fixed, nonzero $M_0$

Comment: Ok.. Please correct me if I'm wrong: the constant nonzero functor maps any morphism of $Mod(A)$ to the identity morphism of $M_0$. Thus, for $F_{M_1,M_2}:Hom(M_1,M_2)\rightarrow Hom(M_0,M_0)$, s.t $F_{M_1,M_2}(\phi)=Id_{M_0}$, we get $F_{M_1,M_2}(\phi_1+\phi_2)(m_0)=Id_{M_0}(m_0)\neq m_0+m_0=Id_{M_0}(m_0)+Id_{M_0}(m_0)=F_{M_1,M_2}(\phi_1)(m_0)+F_{M_1,M_2}(\phi_2)(m_0)$.

Comment: There are some typos in your comment but  apart from that yes, exactly

Comment: So simple.. Thank you very much.
If you'll post it as an answer, I'll accept it and if you will come up with another, less trivial, example, it would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments, a trivial example is given by any nonzero constant functor.

The proof is easy, and you gave it in the comments.

Another, less trivial (and actually very interesting in some instances) example is given by the "free module functor". Indeed, for any $A$-module $M$, you can forget that it's an $A$-module and get a set $UM$, and then you can take the free $B$-module on that: $B[UM]$.

This is also wildly non linear (in this free module, letting $[m]$ denote the generator associated to $m\in M$, $[m]+[n]\neq [m+n]$)

Using the forgetful functor to $\mathbf{Set}$ followed by some functor $\mathbf{Set}\to Mod(B)$ will easily produce tons of other examples.